# Installing Nikon Capture NX2 on 10.12 Sierra

Tags: macos, install

I bought Capture NX2 years ago. I love it for many reasons. Unfortunately, I cannot install it on macOS 10.12 (Sierra). Strangely, I had Capture NX2 on another mac, and it still works after upgrading to Sierra. The new install is the issue. I cannot install it on my new Mac.

It seems to me that it does work on Sierra, but is prevented from installing for some reason. I tried the newer version, Capture NXD, but it truly is a downgrade, for many reasons.

Any idea how to manually transfer the app from my old computer to the new one. I have tried several things, but no luck.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What prevents installation? Which specific things have you tried, and what happened?

Comment: This software is from circa 2006 - I'm surprised it's working at all.  That said, what specifically happened when you tried to install?  Your question isn't at all clear to that point.

Comment: The error message says "the installation failed. The package you are installing is not compatible with this version of macOS. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance."

Comment: I have contacted Nikon. They say it won't work. But it works fine on my old computer, running Sierra. I tried migration assistant, but then all apps need to be transferred from my old computer to my new one. I tried a fix I found on the web using terminal, altering the installation package, but it did not work. I tried popping the program from the apps folder, and putting it on the new computer in the apps folder, but it did not work. I suspect other files are needed. Any idea which files of those would be?

Comment: I recently upgraded to a new iMac and have the same issue. Followed previous suggestions but whilst it installed ok and opens etc it then "crashs" and closes down. No error message.
Looks like I'm going to have to make the leap to Lightroom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when I upgraded from Mavericks straight to Sierra. Capture NX2 broke. However, I had earlier installed Capture NX2 on my wife's computer running Yosemite. In desperation I copy pasted the program from her computer to mine and it is now working in Sierra. This was more by luck than design so I cannot guarantee the same results.

The process I followed was:

1. Disable SIP (system integrity protection). Please check online how to do this. It can be re-enabled later. This step may or may not be necessary but it was what I followed.
2. Uninstall everything Nikon related from Sierra first. Make sure you clean up any Nikon associated files from `HD/Library/Application support` and `HD/Libraries/Preferences` in Sierra. This will have to be done manually.
3. Then copy paste from a Yosemite computer running Capture NX2 2.4.7. The folders and files I copied were:

   - The NIKON software folder from Applications to Applications on new computer.
   - Copy the Nikon folder from `/Library/Applications Support` (It contains a Nikon sub folder which in turn contains a further six sub folders) to `HD/Library/Application Support` on the new computer. Subfolders in Nikon folder are listed below:

     a Capture NX 2

     b Common

     c OptionalPictureControl

     d Picture Control Utility

     e Profiles

     f Uninstaller
   - Copy all Nikon related files from `/Library/Preferences` to `HD/Library/Preferences` on the new computer. These files are listed below:

     a Capture NX 2.plist

     b jp.co.nikon.MCA.plist

     c jp.co.nikon.MCA2.plist

     d jp.co.nikon.Nikon Message Center 2.plist

     e jp.co.nikon.UninstallCenter (This one is a folder)

Thats it. I was surprised it worked as it was a last ditch attempt. I had tried all the other methods I could find on the internet without success. I hope this works for you, but as I said earlier this was more by luck than intent.

I had read online that users who gradually updated their OS incrementally though the various iterations of OS X retained Capture NX2 functionality. Skipping iterations especially after Yosemite was the problem.

**NOTE:** It is crucial to have this working on Yosemite before upgrading to later versions of OS X.

Comment: Fantastic!  I will give it a try this weekend.  I have a copy running on Sierra already.  Hopefully you have identified all the necessary files.  How did you get that list anyhow?

Comment: I couldn't wait for the weekend.  I tried it without disabling SIP, and it worked great!  Thank you so very much.  Too bad I didn't check here first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did! Just copying the files from my old computer, as described above, did't work for me... Instead, I found another solution:

1. Installed Mavericks on an external disk.
2. Installed CNX2 and VNX2, registered the software and made all updates using the Message_Center_2 app in the installed Nikon folder.
3. Mounted the external disk to my new computer running Sierra.
4. Archived and deleted all other programs in the Mavericks Program folder. 5. Moved the Zip-Archive file out of the Program folder.
5. Used the built-in migration assistant to transfer the program from "another computer" (Unchecked all other transfer alternatives).
   Now, only the Nikon folder and it's preferences were transfered, since there were no other programs in the Program folder.

Comment: A bit late to the party but just to confirm that after trying and failing to get Capture NX2 running on Sierra using the manual transfer of files from oldMac to new, following the above advice to use the inbuilt Migration Assistant utility worked a treat. Almost... Capture NX2 launches with my serial number showing so long as I am not connected to the internet. Once I connected back to the net after the Migration Assistant procedure and having launched the app to check it was working it then won't launch, saying'Cannot start the application. It may not be installed properly. Disconect from the